# How to change the style of the Ag-grid header on sorting (React)?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

It is clear from the official doc that I can change the header class using the "headerClass" prop.

However, I want to give the header a different style (specifically color) when its column is sorted.

Any advise about how to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who faced the same problem, you may change the following classes:

```js
.ag-header-cell-sorted-asc {
        color: blue;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .ag-header-cell-sorted-desc {
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```